# Overwrting multiple file using NSIS Script (how Win Zip extractor does)

Tags: file, null, nsis, overwrite

I am writing a script using Null Script which install around 6000 files in `INSTALLDIR` i.e. `C:\ABC folder`.
I have done this using

```
File /r "ABC"
```

in install section.
It is just a simple extractor (no registry entries and no uninstall.exe created during install).

Now, if I run the same exe again then I want my exe to display a message box to the user while overwriting the files containing the options

- Yes,
- Yes too all, or
- exit the installer

i.e. How WinZip software does while extracting the same zip file in the same location multiple times.

If I set the `SetOverwrite` value to `off` then during install (2nd time) my EXE just skips the file installation without notifying the user. Also using `IFFILEEXIST` I can check a single file or `*.*` files but cannot do one to one mapping.

Please suggest how can I implement this. If this question is already posted then please send me the link.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to get this behavior in NSIS when using `File /r`. You might be able to pull off something similar by generating the file list at compile time by executing a batch file with `!system` and then check if each file exists and maybe delete the old one at run-time but you are not going to get the dialog without a custom plugin. NSIS itself only supports basic Abort/Retry/Cancel and Yes/No dialogs.

If you only want to use free tools, why not just use [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org) to create a self extracting archive?